# RStudio Shiny wrong version 1. vs. 0.14.1

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, install.packages

When I am running my shiny app in RStudio I get an error message:

> packages not found. shiny 1.0 required but 0.14.1. available. Check "repos" Option.

I have tried everything but no luck.

** Update
No I have downloaded the package directly from CRAN, this was the result:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/mbaer/Downloads/shiny_1.1.0.tar.gz",
                 repos = NULL, type = "source")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/mbaer/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependencies 'later', 'promises', 'rlang' are not available for package 'shiny'
* removing 'C:/Users/mbaer/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/shiny'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/RCLIEN~1/R_SERVER/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\mbaer\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" "C:/Users/mbaer/Downloads/shiny_1.1.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/mbaer/Downloads/shiny_1.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

---

[This is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CzKY.jpg)

[image]

I have no idea. This is a screenshot.

Comment: I couldn't understand if you have or haven't install shiny from CRAN. Did you try using `install.packages("shiny")` in the console of RStudio?

Comment: Or in the "package" tab, click on "install", type shiny and make sure the "install depencies" box is checked. All should follow normally.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

Tools--> Global Options --> General--> R Version

wrong R Version was selected. #fail

Thank you so much for your attention to my post. Thank you all.

Comment: Feel free to accept your answer so the question is marked as answered. Self-answering questions is encouraged here

Answer (score 0):

This answer still left me wondering a little, so I thought I'd add a bit. This led me to switching from 64-bit R to 32-bit R. Had to re-install all my packages, but then it worked!